# Can we further tighten Gaussian annulus theorem?

Tags: probability, statistics

I am studying Gaussian annulus theorem, eg. p23, thm 2.9 of https://ttic.uchicago.edu/~avrim/MLT18/BHK2017book.pdf, which says

If we generate $d$ Gaussian rvs, say $X \sim N(0, I_d)$, then
\begin{equation}
Pr[\sqrt{d}-\delta \le ||X||_2 \le \sqrt{d}+\delta ] \le 3e^{-c\delta^2}.
\end{equation}

So people say when $d$ is large, $d$ dimensional Gaussian is located in the annulus with high probability. However, I undertand that the probability exponentially decays but it is not sufficient to say "high probability" since the probability decay $3e^{-c\delta^2}$ does not depend on $d$.

So can we obtain a bound that vanishes as dimension $d$? Any thought?

Comment: Squaring, you realize that these bounds give you an interval of order sqrt d around d for the square l2 norm. This agrees with CLT (which is sharp)